# how to solve running gcc failed exist status 1 in mac m1?

Tags: macos, go, homebrew, apple-m1

I have already brew install mingw-w64.
When i check the versions its there.

gcc --version:
`gcc (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3) 11.2.0`.

g++ --version:
`g++ (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3) 11.2.0`

I also run which gcc:
`/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc`

Then I run my docker-compose with image `golang:latest`. No errors yet

```
up to date, audited 370 packages in 10m

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
Unlinking stale socket /tmp/supervisor.sock
[15:30:39] Using gulpfile /go/src/github.com/projectname/src/api/gulpfile.js
[15:30:39] Starting 'default'...
[15:30:39] Starting 'watch'...
```

When I save a .go file it downloads all mods and this is the error:

```
 # github.com/projectname/api
 /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_arm64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
 collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
 compilation terminated.

 [15:46:23] 'build-binary' errored after 1.98 s
 [15:46:23] Error in plugin "gulp-shell"
 Message:
     Command `go build` failed with exit code 2
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.17.0-alpine3.14 AS builder
    
RUN apk update && apk add gcc make git libc-dev binutils-gold

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --update tzdata \
    --no-cache ca-certificates git wget \
    nodejs npm \
    g++ \
    supervisor \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && npm install -g gulp gulp-shell
RUN npm install -g yarn


COPY ops/api/local/supervisor /etc
ENV PATH $PATH:/go/bin
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/projectname/src/api
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and check if, as [in this Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66529210/6309), adding `binutils-gold` would allow you to use `ld`.

```
RUN apk update && apk add gcc make git libc-dev binutils-gold
```

(First seen in [`nodejs/node` issue 4212](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4212))

Comment: this command did solved the ld problem. but leads to another issue

Comment: the next issue is something very hard to explain, can you help start a convo here and ill send some pics?

Comment: @ichimaru I just saw your comments. I will try and follow up tomorrow.

Comment: update comments

Comment: until I can generate a chat ink...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243571/discussion-between-vonc-and-ichimaru).