# why is golang running perfectly fine with supervisor (no error logs) but API not found? using Mac M1

Tags: docker, go, apple-m1, supervisord

OS: MacOS Montery Apple M1.
Stack: Golang, Gulp, Docker, Mongo.

I do not know what the error is. I do not know what to search.

I have come a long way, this is my **first question** [how to solve running gcc failed exist status 1 in mac m1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718772/how-to-solve-running-gcc-failed-exist-status-1-in-mac-m1)
my **second follow up question** [Command `supervisorctl restart` failed with exit code using mac m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771233/command-supervisorctl-restart-failed-with-exit-code-using-mac-m1).
now this is my **third** one.

After all the things I did, the supervisor is running completely fine.
No error logs at `/go/src/github.com/sony/src/api/api_err.log` and `/go/src/github.com/sony/src/api/api_debug.log`

supervisord.conf

```
#!/bin/sh

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
username=admin
password=revproxy

[supervisord]
nodaemon=false
user=root
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
loglevel=info   
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock
username=admin
password=revproxy

[program:sony_api]
directory=/go/src/github.com/sony/src/api
command=/go/src/github.com/sony/src/api/api 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/go/src/github.com/sony/src/api/api_err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile=/go/src/github.com/sony/src/api/api_debug.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
startsecs=0
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17.0-alpine3.14

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --update tzdata \
    --no-cache ca-certificates git wget \
    nodejs npm \
    g++ \
    supervisor \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && npm install -g gulp gulp-shell
RUN apk update && apk add gcc make git libc-dev binutils-gold

COPY ops/api/local/supervisor /etc
ENV PATH $PATH:/go/bin
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/sony/src/api
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:

  ####################################################
  # title:   Sony API
  # author:  Kocera
  # contact: <kocera@sony.com>
  ####################################################

  sony_mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.19-bionic
    container_name: sony_mongo
    # network_mode: "host"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - sony_network
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mongod:/data/db
  sony_api:
    image: go-gin
    container_name: sony_api
    networks:
      - sony_network
    # network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - sony_mongo
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    environment:
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_ENDPOINT=${DB_ENDPOINT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - JWT_API_SECRET_KEY=${JWT_API_SECRET_KEY}
      - JWT_API_SECRET_STRING=${JWT_API_SECRET_STRING}
      - JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY=${JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY}
      - COOKIE_HASH_KEY=${COOKIE_HASH_KEY}
      - COOKIE_BLOCK_KEY=${COOKIE_BLOCK_KEY}
      - UI_DOMAIN=${UI_DOMAIN}
      - UI_ORIGIN=${UI_ORIGIN}
      - HELM_DIR=${HELM_DIR}
      - SMTP_HOST=${SMTP_HOST}
      - SMTP_PORT=${SMTP_PORT}
      - SMTP_USERNAME=${SMTP_USERNAME}
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=${SMTP_PASSWORD}
      - TMC_API_TOKEN=${TMC_API_TOKEN}
    volumes:
      - "../../../:/go/src/github.com/sony/"
    entrypoint:
      [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf && gulp"
      ]
networks:
  sony_network: null
volumes:
  mongod:
    external: true
```

As you can see the docker is running fine...
[image]

I save the go file so it automatically downloads packages, dependencies, libraries, etc.
Now let's go check the gulp watcher, perfectly fine right?

[image]

Now let's test the API using postman
[image]

Comment: If you rebuild your image to _only_ have the Go application - no supervisord, no Node, no unrelated build tools – does it run?  On an M1 Mac, are you sure you have the same processor architecture (x86 vs. ARM) for all of the parts?